Chaining SQL queries / combining SQL queries
I am administrating a WP website that runs an event management plugin.
In order to provide the event onsite team with attendees data via a simple (password-protected) WP page (that is currently set up manually for each event) such as attendee(s) name(s), order-ID, number of tickets sold and the like regarding purchased tickets I am trying to achieve the following:
When ticket orders are placed for a particular event via a dedicated WP [event-]page (with dedicated post_ID), the event management plugin creates the following entries in wp_postmeta as outlined below (for the sake of simplicity I will only refer the db entries that I need to print in the simple WP page mentioned above).
For every ticket purchase the plugin creates a ticket-ID in WP_postmeta that is mirrored by the post_ID of the event-page as follows:
table: wp_postmeta



meta_id
post_id
meta_key
meta_value




12345
0001
event_id
6789


12346
0002
event_id
6789


12347
0003
event_id
6789


12348
0004
event_id
6789


12349
0005
event_id
6789



meta_id: is just a meta identifier of the ticket and is not important to me
post_id: are the individual IDs of the various ticket purchases in ascending order
event_id: is the identifier (post_type) of the parent post
meta_value: is the referring post_ID of the parent WP page (the page that displays the event)
In order to pull these [ticket-]post_ids in column 2 I run the following SQL query:
<?php
global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_value = '6789' AND meta_key = 'event_id' ");
        foreach($results as $result){
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($result->post_id);
            echo '</pre>';
        }

// result: 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005

For each of those [ticket-]post_ids 0001 - 0005 the event plugin creates further meta_values in WP_postmeta of which I need to pull additional values:
table: wp_postmeta



meta_id
post_id
meta_key
meta_value




12350
0001
transaction_id
ABC12345


12351
0001
ticket_number
3


12352
0001
price
57


12354
0001
gateway_label
paypal


12353
0001
attendees
a:3:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"name";s:8:"John Doe";s:5:"email";s:12:"jd@gmail.com";


12354
0002
transaction_id
BCD23456


12355
0002
ticket_number
2


12356
0002
price
38


12357
0002
gateway_label
paypal


12358
0002
attendees
a:3:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"name";s:8:"Jane Doe";s:5:"email";s:13:"j_d@gmail.com";



meta_id: again just a meta identifier that is not important to me
post_id: is the individual ID of the ticket purchase
event_id: is the identifier (role) of the meta_value
meta_value: is the meta value that I need to gather
[Note: 'attendees' is cut short in this post since the serialized data is rather long]
In order to pull these meta_values in column 4 for a particular [ticket-]post_id in column 2 I run the following SQL query:
<?php
global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE post_id = '0001' AND meta_key IN ('transaction_id', 'ticket_number', 'price', 'gateway_label', 'attendees') ");
        foreach($results as $result){
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($result->meta_value);
            echo '</pre>';
        }

// result: ABC12345 3 57 paypal a:3:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"name";s:8:"John Doe";s:5:"email";s:12:"jd@gmail.com";...

So with this rather long introduction here is what I'm trying to achieve:
For each event that consists of several online ticket purchases I would like to pull the above data via a SQL query where I will manually adjust the parent page post_ID (in the example above: '6789'). I read up on JOIN and UNION but that didn't get me any further. For the task I would like to chain (?) / combine (?) the queries and unserialize the data under the meta_key 'attendees' in a way that I get something to the effect of the following output:
<p>Transaction ID: ABC12345</p>
<p>Number of tickets: 3</p>
<p>Amount paid: 57.00</p>
<p>Payment gateway: Paypal</p>
<p>Ticket holder: John Doe</p>
<p>E-Mail: jd@gmail.com</p>

<p>Transaction ID: BCD23456</p>
<p>Number of tickets: 2</p>
<p>Amount paid: 38.00</p>
<p>Payment gateway: Paypal</p>
<p>Ticket holder: Jane Doe</p>
<p>E-Mail: j_d@gmail.com</p>

<p>Transaction ID: CDE34567</p>
...

Any help much appreciated!

You didn't post any SQL code, only PHP code containing some SQL snippets created using string interpolation, risking SQL injection. The PHP code doesn't explain anything. I read up on JOIN and UNION but that didn't get me any further. what does that mean? What did you actually try, and what's the actual SQL queries you tried?  You combine data using JOIN, UNIION, CTEs, subqueries.

unserialize the data under the meta_key SQL doesn't serialize anything, so there's nothing to deserialize. Is the real question how to loop over nested results? Is that why you didn't like the results of JOIN ?

Thanks for getting back promptly! I apologize for mixing up terms. I am somewhat reluctant to run SQL commands on a live database so I prefer to embed them in PHP and test the output on a test WP page (I will add wpdb::prepare() when running this on a live server). With regard to JOIN and UNION I didn't get any printout at all so I assume I must have done something utterly false. I have tried suggestions found here under the tag 'chaining SQL queries' but these didn't elaborate on running queries and using the results in a further query in one go (which I don't even know if that is possible).

Can you please add what you tried with joins as writing you tried it is easy. However, sharing the actual attempt demonstrates that you indeed tried something!

Forget the desirialisation of ticket purchase details in sql - you would have to write the code that parses a php serialised object. Use php for desirialisation as that is a single call to a built-in function.

I would create a separate test environment with manufactured test data to test any newly developed code. Do not ever test on your live environment! You should test your sql queries directly on a database before using them in any applicationcode. This way you will get all the error messges.
